# How to make PdfPTable calculate column-width dynamically

Tags: java, itext

I want to create a PdfPTable with columns containing Strings of different lengths. I learned that the width of each cell/column are the same for each column (default) or one can set the fraction of space every column shall occupy.

However, I want the columns to be as wide as required, but not any wider, depending on the data inserted. Assume that the table fits easily on the page (no breaks!). Of course, I can manually step through all my data and calculate the maximum-String-length of each column, setting the properties of the table accordingly, but I wondered whether such a common option is already provided by itext itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iText is not HTML, so it doesn't have options to automatically adjust width, instead is page oriented and so you've to decide your widths, either as percentage or absolute values.

I'm afraid that to do what you ask, you've to implement your own extension by measuring the widths, as you said. See [how to calculate the string with with iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525986/how-to-calculate-the-string-width-in-itext).

Comment: how to set the width in %?

Comment: @JakobAlexanderEichler using `setWidthPercentage(float widthPercentage)` method on `PdfPTable` instance