# Itext7 center text and fill both sides

Tags: itext7

I am trying to print text to a pdf and I have everything set-up and working so far. I have a line which is 6-inches wide, that is **(6*72) 432** device pixels. What I am trying to do is print text to this line, **center-aliened and fill both sides** to occupy the full width of the line. Example **------Hello there, this is my Text------**. Here is a snippet of my code where I am trying to estimate the space occupied by my text so I can the calculate how much characters to insert before and after.

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA);
canvas.setFontAndSize(font, 12);
System.out.println(font.getContentWidth(new PdfString("Hello there, this is my Text")));
```

This code produces a number in excess of two thousand which far more than 432. Not sure what is the returned units. **How do I estimate the length of my string and center-Aline it within 432dp
?** the extra space must be filled with a special character. Its very similar to the way a cheque is printed where the amount is stated in words and filled on both sides if there is space.

I looked at [this post](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/interactive-forms/how-can-i-find-maximum-character-limit-text-field) and [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525986/how-to-calculate-the-string-width-in-itext) but I am not getting anywhere with this. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the tags of the post you refer to: [How can I find the maximum character limit for a text field?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/interactive-forms/how-can-i-find-maximum-character-limit-text-field) The last tag refers to iText 5, whereas you are using iText 7. In other words: you are looking at the wrong FAQ entry. The iText 7 FAQ entry for that question is: [How can I find the maximum character limit for a text field?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/interactive-forms/itext7-how-can-i-find-maximum-character-limit-text-field) But that doesn't answer your question.

You should read [How to choose the optimal size for a font?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/font-examples/itext7-how-choose-optimal-size-font)

The value you get when you measure text is expressed in glyph space:

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA);
float glyphWidth = font.getContentWidth(new PdfString("Hello there, this is my Text"));
```

It is normal that these lines are insufficient to get the width in user space (which is what you are looking for). Why is this normal? Because the `font` object has no idea of the font size you are going to use.

In your case, you are using a font of 12pt. Hence the width of the `PdfString` is:

```
float width = glyphWidth * 0.001f * 12f;
```

That is the width you are looking for.

Centering that text at an absolute position can be done using the `showTextAligned()` method. There are many alternative ways to achieve this. That could be the subject of another question, because you don't need to do all that Math.

You could just do this:

```
/*
 * Example written in answer to a question on StackOverflow.
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39437838
 */
package com.itextpdf.sandbox.text;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.color.Color;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.PdfCanvas;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.draw.ILineDrawer;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Tab;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.TabStop;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.TabAlignment;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author bruno
 */
public class CenterText {
    class MyLine implements ILineDrawer {
        private float lineWidth = 1;
        private float offset = 5;
        private Color color = Color.BLACK;
        @Override
        public void draw(PdfCanvas canvas, Rectangle drawArea) {
            canvas.saveState()
                .setStrokeColor(color)
                .setLineWidth(lineWidth)
                .moveTo(drawArea.getX(), drawArea.getY() + lineWidth / 2 + offset)
                .lineTo(drawArea.getX() + drawArea.getWidth(), drawArea.getY() + lineWidth / 2 + offset)
                .stroke()
                .restoreState();
        }

        @Override
        public float getLineWidth() {
            return lineWidth;
        }
        @Override
        public void setLineWidth(float lineWidth) {
            this.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        }
        @Override
        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }
        @Override
        public void setColor(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }
        public float getOffset() {
            return offset;
        }
        public void setOffset(float poffset) {
            this.offset = offset;
        }

    }

    public static final String DEST = "results/text/center_text.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new CenterText().createPdf(DEST);
    }
    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        PageSize pagesize = PageSize.A4;
        Document document = new Document(pdf, pagesize);
        float w = pagesize.getWidth() - document.getLeftMargin() - document.getRightMargin();
        MyLine line = new MyLine();
        List<TabStop> tabstops = new ArrayList();
        tabstops.add(new TabStop(w / 2, TabAlignment.CENTER, line));
        tabstops.add(new TabStop(w, TabAlignment.LEFT, line));
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.addTabStops(tabstops);
        p.add(new Tab()).add("Text in the middle").add(new Tab());
        document.add(p);
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you do the Math yourself if iText can do it for you?